# How should a non editable drop down box (combo box) be formatted in Winforms?

Tags: forms

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and drop down box has 3 drop down styles 'simple', 'dropdown' and 'dropdown list'. My drop down box doesn't allow the user to enter a value it contains a fixed number of selectable items. I've been setting the style to 'drop down list' as this doesn't allow editing but I noticed that Microsoft uses 'drop down' instead of drop down list even when the box does allow data entry. What should I set the box to? I want keep the program in line with design standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Drop Down List when the user should not have any editing ability over the items.

Comment: but i cant set backcolor in windows seven